# Workflow lookup over another site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Is there any way to look up items from a soap data source in a workflow with sp 2010?
I have a site (Organization) contains a sub site (Departments) and this sub site contains many other sub sites like Department1, Department2,...
Users list is defined in Organization site. Now, I want to create a workflow in Department1 and check the current user information looking up in user list in Organization site.

How can I do that?
I tried to create a soap data source of Users List in Department1, but I can not look it up in the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default actions in a workflow don't allow you to access lists outside of current site. You would have to create your own custom workflow action to do what you want.